# SQL Query - not working as desired using openquery

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to get the data for the previous day in the below query.

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(SQL32BIT, 'SELECT DISTINCT * FROM OPENQUERY(SQL04, ''SELECT X.* FROM EMPLOYEES X WHERE X.E_JOINDATE = Curdate()'')')
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Declare @MyQuery VARCHAR(4000),
        @printed_datetime DateTime
SET @printed_datetime = DATEADD(dd, - 1, GETDATE())
SET @MyQuery ='SELECT DISTINCT * FROM OPENQUERY(SQL04, 
              ''SELECT X.* FROM EMPLOYEES X WHERE X.E_JOINDATE =''''' + Convert(VarChar(20), @printed_datetime) + ''''''')';
exec(@MyQuery)
```

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY(SQL32BIT,'SELECT DISTINCT * FROM OPENQUERY(EASYSOFT, ''Select X.* from cBRANCH2_BATCH_HEAD X where x.bc_date = {D ''''2018-07-04'''' } ;'')')
is working fine but how can i get the previous day if i want to run this daily

Comment: I just added the previous date. Also, it is useful to add a parameter for dealing with dates. I hope that this be helpful

Comment: Thank you very much Leshua. This was really very helpful to me.